# Python Web Scrape - For Loop Issue

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this little project to web scrape a website. I completed another website for a competitor but I am having a hard time with the current one.

What the code is currently doing is creating a csv file (which is what I want), and in the csv file, I have the headers shown, but no data under it.

Can someone help me with my for loop script. I believe it's not capturing the data in order to write it into the csv file.

Thank you for your help.

Below is the python script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# setting my_url to the wesite
urls = ['https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/North_Carolina/Charlotte/1000000398/Facility.aspx'
    , 'https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/North_Carolina/Charlotte/1000000404/Facility.aspx']

#https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/North_Carolina/Charlotte/1000000398/Facility.aspx?cid=org::maps&utm_source=google&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=org::maps



filename = "extraspace.csv"
open(filename, 'w').close()
f = open(filename, "a")
num = 0

headers = "unit_size, size_dim1, unit_type, online_price, reg_price, street_address, store_city, store_postalcode\n"

f.write(headers)

for my_url in urls:
    # Opening up connection, grabbing the page
    uClient = uReq(my_url)

    # naming uClient to page_html
    page_html = uClient.read()

    # closing uClient
    uClient.close()

    # this does my html parsing
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    # setting container to capture where the actual info is using inspect element

    #-----   <div class="right-col-unit-listings" class="unit-listings"> ==$0    -------this is body of each unit container
    #-----   <div class="results"> ==$0    -------this is body of each unit container
    #grabs each product
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "makesOffer"})

    #-----   <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"> ==$0     -----this is body of address
    #grabs address
    store_locator = page_soup.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "address"})

    f.write("website " + str(num) + ": \n")
    for container in containers:
        for store_location in store_locator:
            street_address = store_location.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"})
            store_city = store_location.findAll("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"})
            store_postalcode = store_location.findAll("spand", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
            title_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "size RamaGothicSemiBold"})
            size_dim = container.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "description"})
            #unit_type = container.findAll("ul", {"itemprop": "description"})
            unit_container = container.ul.li
            unit_type = container.text
            online_price = container.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "price"})
            reg_price = container.findAll("div", {"class": "rate strikeout"})

        for item in zip(title_container, size_dim, unit_type, online_price, reg_price, street_address, store_city, store_postalcode):
            csv = item[0].text + "," + item[1].text + "," + item[2] + "," + item[3].text + "," + item[4].text + "," + item[5].text + "," + item[6].text + "," + item[7].text + "\n"
            f.write(csv)
    num += 1
```

Below is the HTML for containers:

```
<div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <div itemprop="itemOffered" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <div class="guide">
            <div class="size-help-lnk size-guide hidden" data-locker="False" data-square-feet="25">Size Help</div>
            <div alt="5x5" class="video-btn-5x5 video-link" onclick="trackSC('UnitListingVideo');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="size RamaGothicSemiBold">
            <div itemprop="description">5' x 5'</div>
            <div>SMALL</div>
        </div>
        <div class="features">
            <ul itemprop="description">
                <li><i class="check-icon"></i>Enclosed Storage</li>
                <li><i class="check-icon"></i>Indoor</li>
                <li><i class="check-icon"></i>1st Floor Access</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rate strikeout">
            <div><span style="width:100%;"></span>$57</div><span class="StreetRate">IN-STORE</span></div>
        <div class="rate">
            <div content="35.00" itemprop="price">$35
                <meta content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency" />
            </div><span class="WebRate">WEB RATE</span></div>
        <div class="promo"><span style="color:#000;">Act fast:<br/>Limited units</span></div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-orange cta-test is-vehicle" href="https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/ReserveOrHold.aspx?uid=a0GC000000tUNupMAG" id="ctl00_mContent_UnitListPopular_ctrl0_hlReserveLink" onclick="upDown('unitRows|8506|1;05X05|NDN|57|35| | ; | | | | | ; | | | | | ;05X05|CDN|71|48| | ;05X07|CDN|74|50| | ');">RESERVE</a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <link href="http://schema.org/OnlineOnly" itemprop="availability">
    </link>
</div>
```

and finally below is the HTML for the address:

```
< div itemprop = "address"
    itemscope = ""
    itemtype = "http://schema.org/PostalAddress" >
    <span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbAddress"
    itemprop = "streetAddress" > 3304 Eastway Dr < br / > Ste D < /span><br/ >
    <span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbCity"
    itemprop = "addressLocality" > Charlotte < /span>, <
    span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbState"
    itemprop = "addressRegion" > NC < /span> <
    span id = "ctl00_mContent_lbPostalCode"
    itemprop = "postalCode" > 28205 < /span> <
    /div>]
```

Comment: close file at the end - it may not send data to file if you don't close it. And code `open(filename, 'w').close()` may not work because it creates new connection and then it close only this new connection, not old one which you forgot to close.

Comment: @ furas - should I place the close() command at the end of the script ?

Comment: What is your expected output for a single lead? Do you want viewers to go through your code and discover that? Try to be explicit about your requirement.

Comment: @D-Ru yes, use `f.close()` at the end. It is information for Python or system to send on disk all data which can still be in buffer in memory RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one address on the webpage so you only need to fetch it once. So you can get rid on one of the for loops. You had a typo in

```
store_postalcode = store_location.findAll("spand", {"itemprop": "postalCode"})
```

resulting in a None value.

From the zip documentation h[ttps://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

So it stopped on the None value and you didn't get any output. Otherwise it would have stopped after one iteration when the address details were exhausted.

Fixing these your code works:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re

urls = ['https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/North_Carolina/Charlotte/1000000398/Facility.aspx'
    , 'https://www.extraspace.com/Storage/Facilities/US/North_Carolina/Charlotte/1000000404/Facility.aspx']

filename = "extraspace.csv"
open(filename, 'w').close()
f = open(filename, "a")
num = 0
headers = "unit_size_0, unit_size_1, size_dim1, unit_type, online_price, reg_price, street_address, store_city, store_postalcode\n"
f.write(headers)

for my_url in urls:
    uClient = uReq(my_url)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    street_address = page_soup.find("span", {"itemprop": "streetAddress"}).text
    store_city = page_soup.find("span", {"itemprop": "addressLocality"}).text
    store_postalcode = page_soup.find("span", {"itemprop": "postalCode"}).text

    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "makesOffer"})
    for container in containers:
        title_container = container.findAll("div", {"class": "size RamaGothicSemiBold"})
        size_dim = container.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "description"})
        unit_type = container.findAll("ul", {"itemprop": "description"})
        online_price = container.findAll("div", {"itemprop": "price"})
        reg_price = container.findAll("div", {"class": "rate strikeout"})

        for item in zip(title_container, size_dim, unit_type, online_price, reg_price ):
            i= re.match(r"([^A-Z]*)([A-Z]*)", item[0].text.replace('\n', '').strip("\""))
            csv = i.group(1) + "," + i.group(2) + "," + item[1].text + "," + item[2].text + "," + item[3].text + "," + item[4].text + "," \
                  + street_address + "," + store_city + "," + store_postalcode + "\n"
            f.write(csv)
    num += 1

f.close()
```

You could update it if you like to use the Python csv module https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @ Dan-Dev - thank you this works. Although, I'm not sure what you mean by "There is only one address on the webpage so you only need to fetch it once" because I am pulling from multiple websites (same company, but different locations). Is it possible to grab the unit_size and separate the dimensions (5' x 5') from the "SMALL" on different columns?

Comment: What I meant was there is only one address on each web-page (one per URL). Assuming the text you want is the uppercase text you can use the a regular expression I have updated the answer with.